# Editing specific locations of a CSV file with Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that looks as such:

```
header1, header2, header3, header4
1, 2, 3, abc
4, 5, 6, abc
7, 8, 9, abc
```

My goal is to only change the values marked as "abc". I want the file to look like this when I'm done:

```
header1, header2, header3, header4
1, 2, 3, test
4, 5, 6, test
7, 8, 9, test
```

The code I have come up with so far is as follows:

```
import csv

with open('test2-2.csv', 'w') as csvout:
    write=csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r')
    with open('test2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        read=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in read:    
            row[3]="test"
            write.writenow(row)
```

The problem with this code is that it overwrites the "header4" location as well, so it comes out looking like this:

```
header1, header2, header3, test
1, 2, 3, test
4, 5, 6, test
7, 8, 9, test
```

Is there any way to specify the index locations I want to change?

Thanks for any help!

Here is the new code that works with this example:

```
import csv

with open('test2-2.csv', 'w') as csvout:
    write=csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r')
    with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        read=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        header=next(read)
        write.writerow(header)
        for row in read:    
            row[3]="test"
            write.writerow(row)
```

Comment: The code you've given us will raise an `AttributeError` because of a typo. Also, either your CSV files don't actually have those spaces, or your code actually has another parameter in the reader/writer constructors, or it doesn't actually work. Please give us actual runnable code, input, and output, not just vague approximations of it, if you want us to debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for a way to treat the header row separately, that's pretty easy: Just process the first row separately.

```
with open('test2-2.csv', 'w') as csvout:
    write=csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r')
    with open('test2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        read=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        header = next(read)
        write.writerow(header)
        for row in read:
            row[3]="test"
            write.writenow(row)
```

(Note that this still has the same bugs are your original code—at least one typo, `writenow`, a missing `skipinitialspace=True`, etc.)

---

If you want to change things by some different rule, just write a different transformation. As long as you can describe it in English, you should be able to convert it to Python pretty easily.

For example, if you wanted to change any `6` in any column into `test`:

```
for row in read:
    row = ('test' if col == '6' else col for col in row)
    write.writenow(row)
```

Or, if you wanted to change column 2 of row 3 into `test`:

```
for i, row in enumerate(read):
    if i == 3:
        row[2] = 'test'
    write.writenow(row)
```

Or, if you wanted to change any `6` in column 2 of any row:

```
for i, row in enumerate(read):
    if row[2] == '6':
        row[2] = 'test'
    write.writenow(row)
```

… and so on.

Comment: This worked great for skipping over the first line. However, if I wanted to change "6" to "test" as well. Could I specify that location?

Comment: What do you mean 'if I wanted to change "6" to "test"'? Are you looking to change all instances of the value `6` in any column? Or column 2 of row 3? Or…?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your replacing code with an `if` block, and use `enumerate()` (see #added comments):

```
import csv

with open('test2-2.csv', 'w') as csvout:
    write=csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r')
    with open('test2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        read=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in enumerate(read): #modified
            if row[0] >= 1: #added
                row[1][3]="test"
                write.writenow(row)
```

Comment: Why would you go to all this length? If you really want the row number, just wrap `enumerate` around the `read` instead of trying to keep track of it manually like this. But you don't even need it here.

Comment: well, I didn't remember that function, see modified answer.